# Error compiling Xamarin Forms new project

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors, compilation, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build a simple "empty" project from the base template.

I get this error:

> Error initializing task FixedCreateCSharpManifestResourceName: Not registered task FixedCreateCSharpManifestResourceName.

How can I fix it?

On the same machine I can build other Xamarin Forms apps

Comment: Which "empty" project are you using and is it in xamarin studio or Visual Studio?

Comment: Xamarin Studio on mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing same problem read from some forum   https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=32724

Close the Solution or Xamarin Studio and Reopen it.

When I followed it worked.